# Xcode's Accessibility Label vs Hint vs Id

Tags: xcode, label, accessibility, hint

I searched but could not find an up-to-date question, so here goes:

Could someone let me know what Xcodes Accessibility Label vs Hint vs Id are used for?  I think it might be label and hint are used for voiced navigation and Id's are only used for automation, but not sure if that is right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between setAccessibilityLabel and accessibilityIdentifier in ios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21152716/whats-the-difference-between-setaccessibilitylabel-and-accessibilityidentifier)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are correct.

The 'Label' property will be used in voice over representing the element itself. If Labels are not set manually, they will be filled in at runtime based on the content of the element. IE: "Comment Delete Button"

'Hints' are also used in voice over assistance but are a more descriptive representation of the element. IE: "This button allows users to delete a comment."

'identifier' is used for automation and quick query of the UI element. 
IE: "CommentDeleteButton"

The Label and Hint can be localized and therefore will vary between languages while the identifier remains the same.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Accessibility_on_iPhone/Accessibility_on_iPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008785-CH100-SW1

Answer (score -1):

**`accessibilityLabel`** end-user VoiceOver for visually impaired. Should be localized when relevant.

**`accessibilityIdentifier`** developer facing and designed to identify a view for testing and automation. Should not be localized.

**`accessibilityHint`** additional context for `accessibilityLabel`. Should be localized when relevant. Leave blank when `accessibilityLabel` is descriptive enough.